# Database modelling for tables like tree like subcategorization with deeper sub levels

Tags: database

there is doubt in how the following requirement can be converted into database tables. There are deeper levels of sub categorization in the requirements that very dynamically.
The following example will explain my requirement:

category---->

```
         item1
         item2----->

                   sub-item1
                   sub-item2------->

                                 deeper sub item1
                                 deeper sub item2
                   sub-item3
                   sub item4------->

                                  deeper sub item1

                   sub item5

         item3
         item4
```

**In future there can be much more deeper sub items. How to categorize so that database becomes dynamic.**

Comment: you should read up on Hierarchical database modeling. This link has some good basic info on various approaches http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with:

```
ID 
Name 
ParentID
```

So ParentID of zero would be the top level. From there it can go on forever.

Comment: The above solution works only when we know how many number of deeper levels are there. In the above case the number of deeper levels are dynamic and not known previously.

Comment: @GaneshYoganand, this is dynamic. {ParentID=0, ID=100}, {ParentID=100, ID=233}, {ParentID=233, ID=834}, {ParentID=834, ID=1234}.  This is 4 levels and can be built dynamically.

Comment: Got it J Brooks, your answer really cooks, thank u very much for your patient explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Hierarchical storage for the structure of my works flyout menu similar to what you are looking for. The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `page_menu` (
  `menu_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_parent` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `menu_sibling` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `url_id` int(10) NOT NULL,      
  PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`),
  KEY `menu_parent` (`menu_parent`),
  KEY `menu_sibling` (`menu_sibling`),
  KEY `url_id` (`url_id`),
  KEY `lang` (`lang`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `page_menu`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `page_menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_parent`) REFERENCES `page_menu` (`menu_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `page_menu_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_sibling`) REFERENCES `page_menu` (`menu_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `page_menu_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`url_id`) REFERENCES `page_desc` (`url_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `page_menu_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`lang`) REFERENCES `lang` (`lang`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

So basically each record is given its own unique id (menu_id), and also lists an optional parent (root elements being NULL) and optional older sibling (oldest sibling also being NULL) Both of these are foreign keys to the menu_id primary key column to enforce the menu elements being associated with other existing menu elements, and then finally the language and id of the url itself which are linked to other tables that hold the page data for each language version of a page.

So while the rows look like this:

[image]

The structure it holds is this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>11
        <ul>
            <li>61
                <ul>
                    <li>111</li>
                    <li>121</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>71</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>31</li>
    <li>41</li>
    <li>51</li>
</ul>
```

The downside to this method is you can't extract the tree with SQL alone, it takes a little processing to sort the records in the right order before you can easily reconstruct the tree. Basically you have to loop through the results to reorder them into a flattened version of the tree before you can run through it in reverse appending children to parents.. while not dreadly slow, this isnt exactly fast either so its probably not a suitable method for complicated trees that cannot be statically cached in a file. But for simple things like occasionally recreating the nested  structure of a flyout menu (which gets saved as an html include file) it works great.